# Intergration facebook account and ACS account

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-acs

I have a question:

- When I login with Facebook account that have same email with a ACS account (created before by app).
  How can I integrate this Facebook account with my ACS account?

Comment: hi @Maulik ACS = Appcelerator Cloud Service

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to implement the [Facebook Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook.LoginButton) to provide a login-via-Facebook button and retrieve their access token. Then use that to call the ACS/ArrowDB [users/external_account_login](http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/SocialIntegrations-method-external_account_login) endpoint with tho log them into ACS/ArrowDB with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @FokkeZandbergen . If use **external_account_login**, it will create a new user and we could not link with existed user that have the same email.

Comment: Then use http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/SocialIntegrations-method-external_account_link, but of course then the user will first have to login with his ArrowDB/ACS credentials, then login with Facebook after which you'll call this API to link them. Then next time he can also use FB.

Comment: So I will force user login with ACS account first, if they want login with Facebook account?

Comment: Well, only if they already have an ACS account. If you don't offer a way to create an ACS account then just use external_account_login which will create the ACS account without them ever having to know and they can just login with Facebook every time.